# Writing variable's content to a file in single line

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to create a parameter file in shell script. And when i am trying to write variables into the file it is writing it's content in different line.

Input variables

```
var1="1,2,3,4"
var2="100,200,200,400"
var3="10,11,12,13"
```

How i am writing these variables into file

```
echo "VAR1="$var1 >> file.param
echo "VAR2="$var2 >> file.param
echo "VAR3="$var3 >> file.param
```

Expected file content

```
VAR1=1,2,3,4
VAR2=100,200,200,400
VAR3=10,11,12,13
```

But for VAR1 numbers are written in a line and for VAR2 and VAR3 numbers are not written as expected.

```
VAR1=1,2,3,4
VAR2=100
,200
,200
,400
VAR3=10
,11
,12
,13
```

Can anyone please help me why this is happening and how can i prevent it.

Comment: This is weird and I cannot reproduce it. However, why don't you enclose the full string within double quotes? `echo "VAR2=$var2"`?

Comment: Tried that but didn't make any difference. Weirdest of all VAR1 is written properly but others are not.

Comment: Your commands are working for me and producing your desired output in the file.

Comment: What if you say `echo "$var"` in the console? It looks like you have some hidden character mangling your string

Comment: This is not reproducible on my computer. I copied and pasted your code in my system, and I get your expected output

Comment: on console , when echoed variables are showing proper result

Comment: Have you tried setting your `IFS` to empty ? When you echoed the variables, did you make sure you properly quotted them ?

Comment: Same here. I cannot reproduce that on my computer. It could be a problem on Shubham's computer.

Comment: No, I just read about IFS and i think it could be a help

Comment: Thanks guys. Now i am sure there is nothing wrong in my code. Will try to execute on another machine

Comment: I was reading these variables from a file which was saved in windows file format. and therefore there were some special characters stored in variable. These characters were creating problem. On saving the source file for variables in UNIX format everything worked fine. :)